# Get the record by ID in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I am doing some CRUD operations. So I found how to create, update, delete and partial select statement. Why I said partial select means I have three entities called `Person`, `ContactInformation` and `Address`. Relationship between these three objects is `Address` is a foreign key in `ContactInformation` and the `ContactInformation` is the foreign key in `Person`. So now I know the Person ID and how can I get the record (Means I want `Person`, `ContactInformation` and `Address` Record) related to this Person ID. At present I am using

```
    Model model = (Model) this.getCurrentSession().get(
                this.getPersistentClass(), argId);
```

Here Persistent class is `Person.class`. So with this I am able to get the `Person` record but I am not able to get the `ContactInformation` and `Address` records. See the below Image.

[image]

Comment: you should maybe annotate the relation with '''fetch = FetchType.Eager'''

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I am not using annotations I am using hbm.xml files. Is there any equlent of FetchType.Eager in hbm.xml ?

Comment: Call person.getContactInformation(), and you'll get the contact information. Call person.getContactInformation().getAddress(), and you'll get the address.

Comment: Thanks JB Nizet. I got the solution Both you guys are right in either way. I used an entry in hbm.xml like "lazy = false" and its working fine and also I used second approach like "person.getContactInformation()". Now the problem was solved. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hay guys I have one more doubt In thee same way I want to update the record. When I update the record Person record was updated but the rest of the referenced records (Contact Information and Address) those are not updated. Those are creating another record instead of updating. So how can I solve this problem... ? Please help me on this...

Comment: Without seeing the code, we can't tell you how it's wrong. Also, consider ditching the XML files and using annotations. We're not in 2005 anymore.

Comment: For update I am using this.getCurrentSession().update(
     this.getPersistentClass().getName(), argModel); And the Persistent class means Person.class and the values came from UI. I am using SPRIN+Hibernate.

Comment: as for fetching, there are strategies for writing to the db as well. look into cascade="save-update"